# The regular expression how to gets the string containing the content

Tags: python, json, python-re

I have the json data, which are as follows:

```json
'[
{"max":0,"min":0,"name":"tom","age":18},
{"max":0,"min":0,"name":"jack","age":28},
.....
]'
```

Now that I know name=tom, how can I get the dict containing tom through regular expressions?Or there are other better ways?
like this

```json
'{"max":0，"min"：0，"name":"tom","age":18}'
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I think this should be possible, but I just want to ask, why you need to use regex ? It would be easier to use json

Comment: maybe convert JSON to Python dictionary and then search in this dictionary. This will no need regex and it can be more useful.

Comment: Yes, on the one hand, in order to learn the use of regular expressions, on the other hand, there may be a lot of similar data, rather than just one or two elements, will traversal be less efficient than regular expressions?
I don't know clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a list of dicts:

```
lst=[{"max":0,"min":0,"name":"tom","age":18},
 {"max":0,"min":0,"name":"jack","age":28}]
```

Then

```
print(list(filter(lambda x:x["name"]=="tom",lst)))
```

Outputs

```
[{'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'name': 'tom', 'age': 18}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
What I hope is that we don't have to use traversal, but instead use regular expressions, or is there any other more convenient way?

Comment: Like the other answers point out, using the `json` module can be helpful. Regular Expressions would also have to 'traverse' through the whole list in order to find all entries where a certain parameter is set to a specific value.
I'm not sure about the resource consumption. I guess that using the built-in filter function is quicker than deserializing the data to json first, however `json` would probably be the most clean solution...

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your help, because I don't know the specific process of finding regular expressions, so i ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize json file with [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

And then iterate over dictionaries in the usual way. Like this:

```py
import json
from typing import Dict

with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    data: Dict = json.load(f)
for d in data:
    if d["name"] == "tom":
        print(d)
```

Notice that your JSON file is malformed with unusual `：`.
Here is the correct one:

```
[
  {
    "max": 0,
    "min": 0,
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "max": 0,
    "min": 0,
    "name": "jack",
    "age": 28
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
What I hope is that we don't have to use traversal, but instead use regular expressions, or is there any other more convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

As others also mentioned your problem looks like it would be handier to use json.

But if you're limited to regex by whatever, here is a simple regex that would work:

```
{.+\"name\":\"tom\".+}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the build-in `json` module to parse a Json file. The `RegEx` is not the best choice because the Json is a standard format and there are many parsers for it! You can see below how you can use the built-in Python Json parser module.

**test.json:**

```
[
   {
      "max":0,
      "min":0,
      "name":"tom",
      "age":18
   },
   {
      "max":0,
      "min":0,
      "name":"jack",
      "age":28
   }
]
```

**Code:**

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r") as opened_file:
    load_data = json.load(opened_file)
    for elem in load_data:
        if elem["name"] == "tom":
            print(elem)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'name': 'tom', 'age': 18}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without regex, using only strings (assuming `s` has the entire data):

```
idx = s.find('"name":"tom"') + len('"name":"tom"')
idx2 = s[:idx].rfind('{')
dict_json = s[idx2:idx] + s[idx:idx+s[idx:].find('}')+1]
```

`dict_json` will be `{"max":0，"min"：0，"name":"tom","age":18}`

Comment: please mark as answered, if you are considering this answer as such